# How can i hide ko DOM conditions after page render?

Tags: knockout.js

using knocoutjs in my web application.i have **ko if condition** on  my page. After page render i can see the **ko conditions** in DOM. How can i hide ko conditions after render?is there any alternative way to resolve this.

Comment: _Why_?  I can't think what sort of a problem they would cause?  Also KO will continue to use them as and when observables change - and if you aren't updating anything and just want a clean output into your page, perhaps KO isn't the solution you're after.

Comment: @JamesThorpe one use case could be for reusing IDs on the same page based on certain conditions.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I'm not sure how removing KO markup would remove IDs so they could be reused?  That sounds like a bug waiting to happen anyway :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe see my answer below. I wouldn't advise doing it, but it's one particular case where this could be useful.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I think I must be reading the question differently, as in your answer I still see that the knockout stuff is in the DOM (it would be there as comment nodes).  From the way I read it, the OP wants to output something into the page using knockout, then clean up the fact that it was knockout that put it there.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? The Knockout bindings are a part of the DOM. They cannot be hidden short of completely removing them.

Comment: If you simply want to remove the bindings (and the associated behavior) at runtime, look into [preprocessNode](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-preprocessing.html#preprocessing-dom-nodes).

Comment: Hi @crimsonChris, when we inspect the document.Can see the logical conditions.So our team thought this is secuirty issue.This is reason why i am try to resolve this.

Comment: I suggest you have a discussion with your team/manager about what the security expectations really are.

Comment: @crimsonChris yes i had,they are worrying.The Ko condition clearly showing variable names and what is the Business logic if any one follow that variable name they can backtrack to JS file.can assume what is flow on the app.We feel this hole.Thanks for your help :).

Comment: Exposing the *front-end* business logic is not usually a security flaw. If it is, then I would suspect the business logic is flawed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This "problem" is not unique to Knockout. Any web technology that puts logic on the client side can be deduced whether in HTML *or* Javascript. This is why you should be validating both on the client and the server side. [Security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) is not enough.